# I'm learning to write implementation classes separately for an interface in a package, but keep getting errors?

Tags: java, interface, package

This is my interface:

```
  public interface prog56pack2interface
  {
     double add (int v1, int v2);

     double subtract (int v1, int v2);

     double product (int v1, int v2);

     double divide (int v1, int v2);

     String showme ();
  }
```

This is the code for my implementation class:

```
public class prog56pack2implclasses1 implements prog56pack2interface
{
    public double add (int v1, int v2)
    {
        return v1 + v2;
    }

    public double subtract (int v1, int v2)
    {
        if (v1 > v2)
        {
            return v1 - v2;
        }
        else
        {
            return v2 - v1;
        }
    }
}
```

I had 2 main doubts here:

1) why do I get this error when I compile the above code as is

> prog56pack2implclasses1 is not abstract and does not override public class prog56pack2implclasses1 implements prog56pack2interface

2) When I include the "divide()" method that prompts the user for a I/O operation i receive an error: (i have included throws IOException near the method)

> divide(int,int) in prog56pack2implclasses1 cannot implement divide(int,int) in prog56pack2interface.

any comments as to where & why am i wrong would be very helpful.

Comment: For 1) You need to implement _all_ methods of an `interface` (or declare your class as `abstract` and let extensions of your class handle the ones that you haven't).

Comment: Above comment is true ! For 2), I think we need more code than that (your code as well as the stacktrace of the error). If you implement a method from the interface, it shouldn't throw exceptions.

Comment: @Lutzi it compiles when the "throws" is removed but i don;t get it as in why ?? the error is thrown at the execution of the method "divide()" it says "overridden method does not throw IOException"

Comment: I can't help you without seeing the full exception message, your implementation of `divide()` and how you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to implement *all* methods in the first concrete class that implements it. 
2) When implementing an interface that has a method that throws an exception, you do not need to declare that exception in the method that overrides it

Answer (score 1):

The class must implement all methods of the interface (or be `abstract`).

An implementation of an interface method may not throw exceptions that the interface does not declare. In your case, remove the `throws` from your class and use a `try ... catch` instead.